# Controlling DC Motor with Raspberry Pi

Tags: transistors, dc-motor, raspberry-pi

I'm new to both StackExchange and electronics in general.

I want to be able to turn on and off a DC motor using my Raspberry Pi.
I have a breadboard, a 6V DC motor, an NPN Transistor (ST 2N2222), a battery holder that holds 4 AA batteries (and consequently has a P.D. of about 6V), a raspberry pi, and wires. Also, can I use Pulse Width Modulation in this setup, and if so, how? If possible, please include circuit diagrams.

I know that this will be much easier to do using an IC Motor Controller (like L293D), but I want to know if it is possible using a transistor instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the transistor if the current that can pass through it is enough to turn the motor. So basically, only if it's a little toy motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googled "raspberry pi transistor" and found many results that would suit your need.

Make sure the transistor can handle the motors current.

PWM is possible with this configuration.

[image]http://justinzondagh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/2013-06-03-Motor-Switch-NPN-Transistor2-624x365.png

Comment: I'd add a capacitor between 0V and your 6V, size depending on your load and battery quality.

Comment: What is the diode for?

Comment: @geckods to protect the transistor. It's called a flyback diode or a catch diode, or a snubber diode .. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode

Comment: PN2222 is a bad choice here, an N-FET would be much better.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I agree, this was on my early days on EE.SE I wasn't super familiar with the embedded circuit editor so I just used an image I found on the web.