# How to safely use a transistor to control fans

Tags: transistors, resistors, fan, esp32, step-up

I'm working on a project where I control two 12V 80mm fans with an ESP32. I've taken inspiration from various blog posts about fan control on the Raspberry Pi with a transistor (e.g. https://fizzy.cc/raspberry-pi-fan/).

As depicted in this blog post, the transistor is used to control GND connectivity of the fan, to switch it on/off.
The resistor used to "protect" the transistor varies a lot depending on the source (from none, to 680 Ohm, to 1kOhm as used here).

I'll be using the power from a USB power supply (5V out) and a step up module (to ~7V) and control the GND connectivity via the ESP32. Now my problem is, that I find no explanation on how to calculate the appropriate resistor.

**Question:** How can I calculate the value for the resistor, to safely operate the transistor (BC547B, Bipolar Transistor, NPN, 45V, 100mA, TO-92, 3-pin)?

*edit:* I would also have a PN2222ABU transistor available.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. That resistor is called a *base resistor* (as it goes to the base of the NPN transistor used here; there's different types of transistors). It's value depends on the "control" voltage, i.e. your GPIO's "high" voltage, and on the current that should flow through the transistor, and the current amplification of the transistor. This might be a bit broad for a single answer here – but I think researching *base resistors* and how to calculate them might give you a headstart.

Comment: Also see this related question, you'll want the diode shown in the answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195105/controlling-dc-motor-with-raspberry-pi

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the introduction! The GPIOs high voltage is 3.3V, I'll look into that!

Comment: @PeterJ Thank you for the hint with the diode, I'll add that as well.

Comment: @PeterJ I've just purchased a set of diodes. Can you teach me, how to chose what diode works best in this case? (IN4001 (1A 50 V) IN4004 (1A 400 V) IN4007 (1A 1000 V) IN5404 (3A 400 V) IN5406 (3A 600 V) IN5408 (3A 1000 V) RL207 (2A 1000 V), UF4007 (1A 1000 V) FR107 1A 1000 V) FR207 (2A 1000 V), IN5817 (1A 20 V) IN5819 (1A 40 V) IN5822 (3A 40 V), IN4148 (200 mA 100 V) )

Comment: @lisa-thehexbit -- re: diode, first of all it needs in excess of the voltage and current rating of your circuit. Besides that a "Schottky" type is usually better, such as 1n5819 or 1n5822, but I have not looked your list in detail and don't recognize all those parts off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to determine the expected current that the fan will draw.  Let's call it 200 mA (just a wild guess on my part, but you should be able to find or measure it).

Next find the minimum beta of the transistor (I'll assume 50, just for example).  In order to pull 200 mA with a beta of 50, you'll need 200/50 = 4 mA of base current.

In order to get 4 mA of base current, divide the voltage drop from control to Vbe (if output of the control is 3.3 V and the Vbe is 0.6 V, then the drop is 3.3-0.6 = 2.7 V) by the base current.  2.7 V / 4 mA = 675 ohms.

Hope this helps and welcome to the site.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!