# Choose and protect NPN transistor with resistor and diode

Tags: transistors, resistors, diodes, circuit-design

I'm working on my first circuit, controlling closet fans with an ESP32. I did some research drew the following circuit. I control the flow to GND from a 5V USB power supply with the GPIO pin thorugh the transistor. The fans would want 12V, but work with 5V just as well. I use the step-up-module to increase the airflow.

[image: circuit]

The 1k Ohm resistor should protect the base of the transistor (BC547B) and the diode is used as a " flyback diode", to protect the transistor as well. I've gathered that from [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/195108). For this I bought a mix of common diodes (IN4001 4004 4007 5404 5406 5408 RL207 FR107 207 UF4007 IN5817 5819 5822 4148).

The question is, if the transistor is used safely in this circuit and what diode is best used here?

**EDIT:** I've updated the above shown circuit with feedback from the community:

**EDIT 2:** A second update of the circuit.

[image]

Comment: What is the model# of your step up module? The grounds are not quite right (or the NPN is reversed). Please label the grounds

Comment: 1k is too high to switch onto a saturated NPN that may draw >100mA starting up , try 50 to 220 Ohms , any diode will do and is needed on the collector where it is switched. But it would be ok to switch the output load from the low side instead

Comment: The transistor looks like it is in the wrong place - I would expect to see it driving one side of the fan (both circuits).

Comment: @VoltageSpike I have a "MT3608 DC-DC Adapter Step-up module"

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 thank you, I'll reduce the ohm on the resistor and use one of the diodes from the pack, if it's placed correctly in my circuit.

Comment: It’s not correct diode goes to the switch and Vcc

Comment: @PeterSmith is that so? Shouldn't that be anyways, as I control the flow to the step-up module and thereby the flow of the currency to the fans?

Comment: Which 3608 module?  The 3608 chip has an "enable" input that would make this much simpler.  Your module might have the "enable" pin available to use.

Comment: It is far simpler to just power the 9V converters and pull the low side of the fan down with the transistor.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm afraid I don't understand. VCC, meaning the 5V+ and switch for the transistor? So the same orientation, just before entering the step-up-module?

Comment: Your diodes as placed have nothing to do with protecting the transistor.  They might provide some protection to the booster module, but it probably doesn't need it.

Comment: @JRE I'm not sure, here's the pinout to the module I have https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1509/1638/files/MT3608_Step_Up_Modul_Pinout.pdf

Comment: Nope, no "enable" pin.  Oh, well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagram lacks grounds but I can get the idea.

It would be better to switch the 9V with the transistors. The current will be lower and the step-up module may have some nasty characteristics (like a big input capacitor) that could cause problems when it switches on. The DC current switching the 5V might be in the 75mA range vs 35mA switching the fan directly.

The purpose of the resistor is not just to prevent the transistor from dying but to control the base current so that it saturates when on. The 1K may be a bit too high for that purpose. BC547B is okay with Ic/Ib = 20.

With 3.1V drive and 0.7 Vbe the base current is 2.4V/R. So for 75mA you'd want about 620 ohms and for 35mA 1K or 1.3K is okay.

As far as the diodes go, I am not sure they are actually necessary, even with the transistor switching the fan directly, but it costs little to add them. Any of the types mentioned are fine. I would use 1N4148s or 1N400x.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPn6gp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The only disadvantage of leaving the DC-DC converter(s) running all the time is a bit more power consumption from the quiescent current the step-up converters draw, but it should not be much in comparison to the ~1W the fans draw in operation.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for the elaborate answer! I have a lot to learn, this is my first circuit, I came up with. I've added your suggestions to the revised version of my circuit in the question!

Comment: Ok, but don't forget the grounds or it won't work, and could even cause damage.

Comment: This is exactly what I said

Comment: Illuminati confirmed.

Comment: Except I explained the reasons for the diode. Hey are you busy with any projects?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Typically there is no need of a diode for the usual 2-phase brushless fan.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75   A few interesting ones that have been on the back burner, nothing major so far in Jan.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thank you very much for your input, it's greatly appreciated! Don't I have grounds connectivity as shown in my circuit from the 5V USB power supply? Did I draw it wrong, or am I missing something?

Comment: Probably, but it would be better to show it explicitly on the diagram. There are connections from V- in to V- out on the modules and maybe there is only one USB power supply, which also supplies the MCU or you will need to add wires.

Comment: I’m working getting a major contract that might interest you in collaboration.  Search Infineon wheel speed sensor IC

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Interesting. TPMS possible eh? If you have enough to talk, can email. my address is muntzed in [this](https://www.electronics-related.com/showthread/sci.electronics.design/343458-1.php) interaction.

Comment: No Wheel Speed Sensor for validation and fault injection project with digital control of analog variables

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the diode is quench the stored energy in an switched off inductive load.

Your transistor is the switch so it needs the diode, ... which could in practice will switch the output better than the input to the boost converter.  Presuming that the no load current is ok when the fan is off and boostconverter still running.

- it is wise to move the switch to the output and switch the fan -ve with the diode you have placed there. The fan load appears like a damped resistive load with a capacitance in parallel as it commutates at some freq. due to internal caps. (.i.e. the current rises linearly with voltage)
- yet accelerating the voltage changes will draw more current until  steady state.
- The boost converter will have more surge current than the fan . **This is why it is better to switch the output and easier on the low side of the load.**

Comment: Hello Tony - thank you very much for your help! I'm very new to all of this and tried to understand. I've updated the circuit in the original question. Would you have a look? I hope I didn't mess up your advice too much.

Comment: @emma.makes - disconnect the GNDOUT from the transistors; connect GNDOUT to GNDIN (this will be your common ground), Connect the transistor emitter to ground and the collector to the low side of the fan,

Comment: @PeterSmith Thank you for the feedback! I've revised the circuit in the question